# Search multiple string arrays

Tags: android

I want to search for one item, in multiple string arrays. If we got a string array containing item 1;2;3 and a string array containing 2;4;5 then if the user searchs for item 2, the system would print out the name of string array 1 and 2. However, if the user searchs for item 4, the system would only print out the name of string array 2. How can this be done? 
 If I wasn't clear enough, and you got some questions then feel free to ask. 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: This has nothing specific to Android...

Comment: it must be your assignment and you need us to write a code for you No way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isn't this just as simple as searching each string array in a for loop, then outputting the name if it is found, and not outputting if its not found

Comment: yes, but I dont want the loop to stop at the first string it finds, I want it to search all possible string arrays. Do I have to give each string array an ID or something?

Comment: there's no reason it would stop at the first string it finds unless you tell it to stop.

if you are comparing these string arrays, you may want an array of string arrays